# Why does this sentence use a present perfect tense?

Tags: tense

> With China's development, there has been an exponential surge of
>   students studying abroad.

What is the difference with a using of past tense or Simple present tense?

Comment: Can you give an example with your idea of past and simple present, please.

Comment: With China's development, there was an exponential surge of students studying abroad.

Comment: With China's development, there is an exponential surge of students studying abroad.

Comment: An exponential rate of increase becomes quicker and quicker as the thing that increases becomes larger: "Cambridge Dictionary"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use the present perfect for actions or states in the past which **have a connection with the present**.

In the sentence *With China's development, there has been an exponential surge of students studying abroad* the point is that this tendency started in the past (we don't know when exactly) and the situation is still the same, i.e. student still go studying abroad quite often.

It would be incorrect to use the present simple or some past tense in this particular sentence.

*There was an exponential surge of students studying abroad* means it's over and one can't observe the same surge these days.

We'd better avoid the present simple here because basically we mean *Since the beginning of China's development, there has been an exponential surge of students studying abroad*. We are not talking about a repeated action or state. We are talking about something that started in the past and hasn't finished yet.

Comment: then... why don't use present perfect continuous tense?

Comment: Because in this sentence the notional verb is the verb "to be". We can't use it in the present perfect continuous ("there has been being" is impossible).